# Cypress is ignoring host file redirection after laptop change

Tags: cypress, hosts

I have a suite of tests to run against pre-production versions of a website, and which can only be accessed through host file redirection as the URL for all versions of the website are the same. Recently, I was supplied with a new laptop, and since then when I attempt to run the test suite, Cypress is ignoring the host file redirection and running against our production environment. A coworker has the exact same version and test suite and it does not ignore the host file redirection.

Uninstalled/reinstalled cypress. Deleted and re-cloned the test suite. Verified that I can redirect my host file locally. Tried to use a different IP address in the Cypress host file redirection to see if it did anything (it did not).